# After click show element in console

Tags: javascript

I need a help. I have a button in html with class "rekapitulace". And i want to do if a user click on that button, it will show a item in text input with class "jmeno". I wrote this but it isnt correct. Any solutions?

```
function rekapitulaceButton() {
var rekapitulaceButton = document.getElementsByClassName('rekapitulace')
rekapitulaceButton.addEventListener('click', precistUdaje)
}

function precistUdaje() {
var jmeno = document.getElementsByClassName('jmeno')
localStorage.setItem('local-jmeno', jmeno)
console.log(localStorage.getItem('local-jmeno'))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns all elements of provided class name, not just a single element. Notice how the name of that method contains plural *elements* word.

To get the first element, you can do:

```js
const rekapitulaceButton = document.getElementsByClassName('rekapitulace')[0];
```

Another possibility is `document.querySelector()`, which always returns one element (first match) or `null`:

```js
const rekapitulaceButton = document.querySelector('.rekapitulace');
```

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByClassName('rekapitulace') return a nodelist array so if you need return an one node elment using id instead of class

```
document.getElementById('rekapitulace')
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you may be misusing localStorage for your debugging. The second argument of .set should be a string.

As mentioned already, you should really try to use IDs instead of classes for targeting the right input, and document.getElementsByClassName returns multiple elements and not just one element.